# Using a cursor in a trigger to change subject of db_sendmail

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cursor, sp-send-dbmail

SQl Server 2008 R2 - I have a trigger that's set up to send an email to a specific email address that is monitored by a third party system which sends out messages to certain groups of people based upon the subject of that message. The limitation to this is that only one group number can be in the subject per message. But I need to send the same message from the trigger to at least two groups meaning that two separate emails must be generated with two different subject lines. I'm thinking possibly a cursor in the trigger would accomplish this but I'm not sure how to write it.
So in the code below I have @cat in which I need to send an email with the subject 'ED' EVERY time the trigger kicks off. I then need to send another email with the subject being set based on the condition of the case statement currently used to set the subject line. I've updated the code as follows and by removing the scalar variables have moved to a set based trigger(??) I've also created and inserted the information into an "email" table that will have a service set up to run every 10 sec and email all records that are set as 0 and then update the flag to 1.

New Code -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_BatchEmail] (
    [BatchEmailID] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    ,[To] [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'someemail' --will never change
    ,[Body] [varchar](255) NULL
    ,[Subject] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
    ,[Profile] [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Alert' --will never change
    ,[OrderID] [varchar] (25) NULL
    ,[OrderDateTime] [datetime] NULL
    ,[SentDateTime] [datetime] NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT msg_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (BatchEmailID)
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



  ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[VeOrders] ON [dbo].[Orders]
        FOR INSERT
        AS
            SELECT @visitid = i.VisitID
    ,@priority = Priority
    ,@cat = Category
    ,@procedure = OrderedProcedureName
    ,@orderid = OrderID
    ,@orderdate = OrderDateTime
    ,@locationid = CurrentLocationID
    ,@roomid = CASE 
        WHEN RoomTreatmentID IS NULL
            THEN 'No Room#'
        ELSE RoomTreatmentID
        END
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN livedb.dbo.EdmPatients edp
    ON edp.VisitID = i.VisitID
WHERE Priority = 'STAT'
    AND Category IN ('CT', 'MRI', 'XRAY', 'US', 'NUC', 'ECHO')
    AND CurrentLocationID = 'ED'

IF @cat IN ('CT', 'MRI', 'XRAY', 'US', 'NUC', 'ECHO')
    AND @priority = 'STAT'
    AND @locationid = 'ED'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @subject VARCHAR(500)

    SET @msg = @roomid + '-' + @procedure + '-' + @priority + '.' --+ 'Order DateTime/Number ' + @order + '/+ @locationid + ' '  + @orderid
    SET @subject = CASE 
            WHEN @cat = 'US'
                THEN 'Test Ultra Sound'
            WHEN @cat = 'CT'
                THEN 'Test C T'
            WHEN @cat = 'XRAY'
                THEN 'Test X-Ray'
            END

    INSERT INTO livedb.dbo.tb_BatchEmail (
        Body
        ,[Subject]
        ,OrderID
        ,OrderDateTime
        )
    SELECT Body = @msg
        ,[Subject] = @subject
        ,OrderID = @orderid
        ,OrderDateTime = @orderdate

END
```

Old Code -

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[VeOrders] ON [dbo].[Orders]
FOR INSERT
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.EdmPatients
        WHERE CurrentLocationID = 'ED'
        )
    RETURN

DECLARE @priority VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @cat VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @procedure VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @orderid VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @locationid VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @roomid VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @visitid VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @visitid = VisitID
    ,@priority = Priority
    ,@cat = Category
    ,@procedure = OrderedProcedureName
    ,@orderid = OrderID
    ,@locationid = CurrentLocationID
    ,@roomid = CASE 
        WHEN RoomTreatmentID IS NULL
            THEN 'No Room#'
        ELSE RoomTreatmentID
        END
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN dbo.EdmPatients edp
    ON edp.VisitID = i.VisitID
WHERE Priority = 'STAT'
    AND Category IN ('CT', 'MRI', 'XRAY', 'US', 'NUC', 'ECHO')
    AND CurrentLocationID = 'ED'

IF @cat IN ('CT', 'MRI', 'XRAY', 'US', 'NUC', 'ECHO')
    AND @priority = 'STAT'
    AND @locationid = 'ED'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @subject VARCHAR(500)

    SET @msg = @roomid + '-' + @procedure + '-' + @priority + '.' 
    SET @subject = CASE
            WHEN @cat = 'CT'
                THEN '55194'
            WHEN @cat = 'US'
                THEN '59843'
            WHEN @cat = 'XRAY'
                THEN '70071'
            END

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
         @recipients = N'someemail'
        ,@body = @msg
        ,@subject = @subject
        ,@profile_name = 'Alerts'
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR logical flaw. It assumes that there will only ever be a single row in inserted. SQL server executes a trigger once per operation, not once per row. You need to make your triggers set based so they can handle multiple rows.

Comment: Sean - Could you elaborate a little? I've read about set based queries before but my understanding was that was more for update statements when multiple rows could be updated at one time. Would inserting the records into another table to be used with a separate email service like @Bill Gregg suggested correct that? I'm just not sure? Any help is appreciated. I should have qualified my post with this is my first attempt at triggers.

Comment: I much prefer the idea of a holding table for this type of thing. That means you don't have to wait on sending an email when you are inserting data into a table. I can't say it would fix the problem because if you are using scalar variables you still have the multiple row issue. Keep in mind that inserts can be multiple row just as easily as an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate out the concerns from creating the emails and sending them. Have a service whose only job is to send emails. Emails are abstract in that they all have a From, a To, a Body, and a Subject. Create a table (named BatchEmail for example) that holds all of those fields.

Then your trigger is simple. It just inserts into your BatchEmail table in a normal select statement.

```
insert into BatchEmail
(To, Body, Subject, Profile)
select N'someemail',
       @msg,
       CASE
            WHEN @cat = 'CT'
                THEN '55194'
            WHEN @cat = 'US'
                THEN '59843'
            WHEN @cat = 'XRAY'
                THEN '70071'
            END,
        'Alerts'
```

Your BatchEmail table should have some column or flag indicating when or if it was sent.

Your service (or even the Insert Trigger on the table, if you really love triggers) Could just select 1 row at a time that hasn't been processed.

```
while true
begin

    select top 1 
           @BatchEmailID = batchEmailID,
           @To = to,
           @From = from,
           @Body = body,
           @Subject = subject,
           @ProfileName = ProfileName
    from BatchEmail
    where processed = 0

    if(@BatchEmailID is null)
    break;

    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @To, @Body, @Subject, @ProfileName

    update BatchEmail
    set processed = 1
    where BatchEmailID = @BatchEmailID

end
```

If you still would rather not have a separate service and insist on doing all of this in the trigger, you could turn @BatchEmail into a table variable, still with a @Processed bit column and select 1 row at a time, updating @Processed after each row.

Comment: So would the batchEmail table then just continue to grow? For each new "trigger" another two or more rows would be inserted into the table and emailed out accordingly then setting batchEmailID = 1 for said records? If that's the case is there a performance reason or some other reason to do that over keeping it in the trigger? Because the batchEmail table could become quite large over time and I would then need to add additional steps to delete records after a while. If I keep it in the trigger itself I wouldn't have to worry about cleaning up the batchEmail table? Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: You didn't misunderstand me. And yes, they would grow, so you'd have to purge them eventually (if you wanted to. Disk space is still pretty cheap.) Your business might like having the data around. Personally I don't like having magic like that in triggers. Triggers are not easily discoverable, and it won't be clear to everyone how those emails are sent. Better to have a dedicated process that everyone can see. IMO. Just because you CAN do something in a trigger doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I have been working on setting this up as you suggested when I thought of another potential issue. I need these emails to be fired off in near real time or as close to real time as the db can do it. These are orders for xrays etc. that come from a hospitals ER dept that are order 'Stat' and the email needs to be sent to the xray tech as soon as possible. If I put the email in what I'm equating to essentially as an email queue, from what I've read today I'd probably need to Create a QUEUE to fire these off. Would that be the right approach and would that still be fairly instant?

Comment: You don't need a QUEUE to fire these off instantly, or quickly. Not sure what you are doing, but if you are keeping the logic in the trigger it will be instant. If you are creating a permanent table then you can schedule your code that processes the table to run as often as you'd like. Or make it a service that is always running and every 5 seconds signs in looking for new rows.